# Transform nested dictionary in Pandas DataFrame to column representation

Tags: python, json, list, pandas, dataframe

I received the response data in Python using `requests` library and transform it into json using `.json()` function. Then used `.json_normalize()` function to receive output in clear DataFrame format.

But here is the issue: values in one of my are nested dictionary (dict in dict) looking like this:

```
   ID   Sec Type
    0   20  [{'id': '3233790e-1f47-403a-bb97-58a14a2f92ab', 'values': [{'number':50, 'level':1}]}]
    1   30  [{'id': 'bbc9852c-ac76-4ecd-9afb-dd371f3bd48b', 'values': [{'number':40, 'level':2}]}]
    2   40  [{'id': 'be5629e0-458d-4aaa-b2f8-77d8ad1b0f7f', 'values': [{'number':30, 'level':3}]}]
```

Honestly, I have not faced with these kind of situations and a little bit confused. Is there any options in Pandas to display this data in normal column way or I need to create something with for loop to parse it row by row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use lambda to extract the data into columns:

```
data = [
[0,   20,  [{'id': '3233790e-1f47-403a-bb97-58a14a2f92ab', 'values': [{'number':50, 'level':1}]}]],
[1,   30,  [{'id': 'bbc9852c-ac76-4ecd-9afb-dd371f3bd48b', 'values': [{'number':40, 'level':2}]}]],
[2,   40,  [{'id': 'be5629e0-458d-4aaa-b2f8-77d8ad1b0f7f', 'values': [{'number':30, 'level':3}]}]],
        ]

data = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['id', 'sec', 'type'])
data = data.set_index('id')
data['sec_id'] = data.loc[:, 'type'].apply(lambda x: x[0]['id'])
data['number'] = data.loc[:, 'type'].apply(lambda x: x[0]['values'][0]['number'])
data['level'] = data.loc[:, 'type'].apply(lambda x: x[0]['values'][0]['level'])
data = data.drop('type',axis=1)
print(data)
```

output:

```
    sec                                sec_id  number  level
id                                                          
0    20  3233790e-1f47-403a-bb97-58a14a2f92ab      50      1
1    30  bbc9852c-ac76-4ecd-9afb-dd371f3bd48b      40      2
2    40  be5629e0-458d-4aaa-b2f8-77d8ad1b0f7f      30      3
```